# adjustFontSizeToFitWidth takes too long to render localized price value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using adjustFontSizeToFitWidth to resize the localized price on the pop up placeholder. This is the Swift code:

```
let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(...))
textField.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 50)
textField.text = product.localizedPrice()
textField.adjustFontSizeToFitWidth = true
self.addSubview(textField)
```

It functions as expected, the only issue is that it takes more than a second to render. How could I improve this?

Comment: Are you saying that if you comment out the `textField.adjustFontSizeToFitWidth = true` line, the delay is completely gone?

Comment: @rmaddy yes, exactly